# How to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu on 2 hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm totally clueless when it comes to Linux and its distributions. I'm also not very used to the command-line, but I thought maybe I could use Ubuntu and learn more about it. I have two hard drives, one has Windows XP and the other is empty. I want to install Ubuntu on the empty drive without erasing anything from the other one. Is there a way?

I don't know about GRUB either, so can you guys help me?

Comment: there a lot of tutorial on Internet like this http://www.wikihow.com/Dual-Boot-Windows-XP-and-Ubuntu

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at those but they were confusing at parts. Particularly with partitions. I have 2 HDDs, but is it required to make a partition anyway? Should I just install it normally on the second drive?

Comment: Is is ok to have just one partition on each hard drive. The installer should create that for you automatically.

Comment: I'll see what I can do then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can just follow the instructions Hany gave you, but since you want to install them on two discs you should check the `something else` option in the installation process. Now you should make all partitions needed. In [this](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/07/23/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7-on-a-computer-with-2-hard-drives/) article they describe the partitions, they choose to make a separate /home partition, this is sometimes useful because all your application settings en personal documents are saved there, and when you reinstall these remain untouched. but you can also just make a /boot, a swap and a / partition (just fill all the left over space with /)